# Align image and text virticaly inside the div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a div with a 30px heigh having an image and a span inside of it aligned to the same lane.

```css
div {
  height: 30px;
  width: 80px;
  outline: 1px solid black;
}
.image {
  height: 16px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
span {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img class='image' src="http://s16.postimg.org/uiq5bnwm9/place.png">
  <span>Places</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To vertically center the elements, use the `::before` pseudo element, then make it `inline-block`, the same height as its parent, and `vertical-align: middle`.

```css
div {
  height: 30px;
  width: 80px;
  outline: 1px solid black;
}
div::before {
  display:inline-block;
  content:'';
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.image {
  height: 16px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
span {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img class='image' src="http://s16.postimg.org/uiq5bnwm9/place.png">
  <span>Places</span>
</div>
```